# Deeplink not working on a certain page but works on others

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net, deep-linking

I'm trying to add deeplinking to a page that requires it.

But for some reason it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#takeMeBack').click(function () {
            if (isMobile.any()) {
                //window.location.replace('DeepLinkingTest://validate');
                window.location.replace('DeepLinkingTest://');
            }
        });
    });
```

button:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="takeMeBack" runat="server" Text="Take Me Back To The App" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-block"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: what has android got to do with this question?

Comment: @MatthewCarpenter I'm deeplinking to an android